How do I set .env file using poetry in Google Colab?
I'm using Google Colab for my Python project. I have created pyproject.toml using !poetry init.
Can you please help me to load environment variable using poetry? I have .env file.

In order to read .env from poetry you can use Poetry Dotenv Plugin . You can install it by:
poetry self add poetry-dotenv-plugin

Example:
$ cat .env
MY_ENV_VAR='Hello World'

$ poetry run python -c 'import os; print(os.environ.get("MY_ENV_VAR"))'
Hello World


thanks for your code. But I have .env file which I want to use in my code, not environmental variables. Can you please suggest me how do I use .env file?
